# gremlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph

I am setting up janusgraph with cassandra on a server. I am getting the following mentioned error. Also what changes are to be made in config file while deploying it on server.

Linux server with JanusGraph 0.4.0, Cassandra 3.11.0

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
```

==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :> ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames()
gremlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: gremlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.registerLookUpInfo(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Have you looked https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1217 ? there is a similar error when ES was not started

Comment: Yes I have gone through it. But when I use bin/janusgraph.sh status it gives ES is working with a process ID. Hence I don't think that's a problem. Its something related to ConfiguredGraphFactory. But my static graph are also not working. Its giving following error : org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphConfigurationException: Cannot determine local host

Comment: Can you please share how to configure ElasticSearch so that I can try once again

Comment: May be your janusgraph is in unhealthy status or even when janusgraph is up before the cassandra and ES then it won't work fine.So first stop the janusgraph and again up.So by this, we can make sure that janusgraph is in process only after cassandra and ES is up.

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs when trying to run the docker image on an arm64 architecture, such as a Mac M1.

I forked the janusgraph docker repo -
https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker

If you don't want to build it yourself, you can use this image -

```
docker pull savantly/janusgraph:0.6.1-arm64
```